# In Oracle PL/SQL Script, set all record's [FIeldX] value to the same value?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've written an Oracle DB Conversion Script that transfers Data from a previous singular table into a new DB with a main table and several child/reference/maintenance tables. Naturally, this more standardized layout (previous could have, say `Bob/Storage Room/Ceiling` as the `[Location]` value) has more fields than the old table and thus cannot be exactly converted over.

For the moment, I have inserted a record value (ex.) `[NO_CONVERSION_DATA]` into each of my child tables. For my main table, I need to set (ex.) `[Color_ID]` to 22, `[Type_ID]` to 57 since there is no explicit conversion for these new fields (annually, all of these records are updated, and after the next update all records will exist with proper field values whereupon the placeholder value/record `[NO_CONVERSION_DATA]` will be removed from the child tables).

I also similarly need to set `[Status_Id]` something like the following (not working):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (STATUS_ID)
VALUES
    -- Status was not set as Recycled, Disposed, etc. during Conversion
    IF STATUS_ID IS NULL THEN
        (CASE
            -- [Owner] field has a value, set ID to 2 (Assigned)
            WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(OWNER)) IS NOT NULL THEN 2
            -- [Owner] field has no value, set ID to 1 (Available)
            WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(OWNER)) IS NULL THEN 1
        END as Status)
```

Can anyone more experienced with Oracle & PL/SQL assist with the syntax/layout for what I'm trying to do here?

---

Ok, I figured out how to set the 2 specific columns to the same value for all rows:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET COLOR_ID = 24;
UPDATE INV_ASSETSTEST
SET TYPE_ID = 20;
```

I'm still trying to figure out setting the `STATUS_ID` based upon the value in the `[OWNER]` field being `NULL/NOT NULL`. Coco's solution below looked good at first glace (regarding his comment, not the solution posted, itself), but the below causes each of my `NON-NULLABLE` columns to flag and the statement will not execute:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(STATUS_ID)
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN STATUS_ID IS NULL THEN
            CASE
                WHEN TRIM(OWNER) IS NULL THEN 1
                WHEN TRIM(OWNER) IS NOT NULL THEN 2
            END
    END FROM TABLE1;
```

I've tried piecing a similar `UPDATE` statement together, but so far no luck.

Comment: where do you have the `OWNER` from? please describe what shall the statement do.

Comment: @PavelGatnar, I believe what you are asking in the comment within the code I provided?? I'm attempting to check the `[Status_ID]` field for a value -- if `NOT NULL` set the `[OWNER]` value to `2`, else (`NULL`) set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (STATUS_ID)
VALUES
    (
    case
        when TATUS_ID IS NULL THEN
        (CASE
            -- [Owner] field has a value, set ID to 2 (Assigned)
            WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(OWNER)) IS NOT NULL THEN 2
            -- [Owner] field has no value, set ID to 1 (Available)
            WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(OWNER)) IS NULL THEN 1
        END )
    end);
```

Comment: That is invalid SQL. You can't reference a column of a table in the `values` clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that appears to be exactly the problem I am having with my original posted attempt. Any suggestions for going about what I am after?

Comment: insert into test(id)
select case 
          when id is null then
              case 
                when trim(owner) is null then '1'
                when trim(owner) is not null then '1'
              end
       end
from test;

Comment: @coco, I thought this might be the solution, but when I try this I'm getting an error for each of my columns that does not accept a `null` value. I've got the data present, I just need to cycle through it and do as described and set the `Status_ID` as either 1 or 2 where in the records the `[Owner]` is `NULL/NOT NULL`.